# Adding my own method in selenium sever

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

i need to add my own defined methods in selenium server. i downloaded the latest jar and unpacked it. Now i need to add my methods. Anyone please tell me how to add my own method in Selenium Server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy. You will need to download the source files from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout

Then add your own methods: start with SeleniumDriverResourceHandler (if you're using RC) or WebDriverCommandProcessor (if you want to use webdriver).

Then compile with ./go selenium-server-standalone